# A word for 'lack of disturbance'

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word that describes the calmness of the person/situation. Ex:

> The surface of the river is *lacking a disturbance*.
>
> The meeting went fine - it *lacked any disturbance* (that could have been present if there were disagreements between attendees).

Comment: Well, of course, *calm* fits to describe the calmness of a situation, and works for rivers, lakes, seas and meetings.

Comment: Tranquil can also be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appropriate words for calmness sometime vary based upon the circumstances.

"The surface of the river is **still**"

"The meeting went fine - it **was uneventful**"

Your question suggests a word that fits somewhat in both circumstances: **calm** and synonym for it, which could also fit in both circumstances include **tranquil** and **peaceful**.

A meeting could be **harmonious** or **constructive**, but neither would apply to a river.

Answer (score 2):

If your you're looking for one word for both examples, how about *smooth*?

> The surface of the river was *smooth*  -- it lacked any disturbance.
>
> The meeting went *smoothly* -- it lacked any disturbance.

M-W:

> [*smooth*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smooth): having a
>   flat, even surface : not rough : not having any bumps, ridges, or
>   uneven parts / happening or done without any problems